# "that a big deal" or "that big a deal"?

Tags: word-order, predeterminers

[**Source**](http://fmovies.to/film/friends.q8mj/w183kk) From an episode of *Friends* at 00:01

> Monica: Will you let it go? **It's not that  big a deal**.
>
> Ross: **Not that big a deal?** It's amazing! OK. Just reach in there and there's just one little manoeuvre *bam!* — a bra right out the sleeve.

I always believed ***‘that a big deal’***  to be correct until I watched this episode of  'Friends' series where *It's not that big a deal* was used so frequently,  I am now beginning to doubt my belief that *not that a big deal* is grammatically correct.

So, which one is grammatically correct?

1. it's not that a big deal
2. it's not that big a deal

And why does the indeterminate article, ‘a’, come *after* the adjective *big* and not before in the Friends' excerpt?

Comment: What she says is "It's not **that** big a deal."

Comment: @StoneyB,Yeah.And that is grammatically incorrect.This is what I think.

Comment: No, that's a common idiom. "(How big is it?) It's not *that* big*" = "It's not so big as that".

Comment: @StoneyB Note that the USAianism is "It's not **as** big as that", for some reason.

Comment: Even if #2 is grammatically incorrect, that's the correct idiomatic phrase. #1 just sounds SO WRONG...

Comment: I would guess where some of the confusion arises is that "that" in this case is an adverb meaning "to a given degree" and thus modifies an adjective

Comment: "A big deal" is a good phrase.  In a question, you could say "Is that a big deal?"  You would be comparing "that" to "a big deal".  In #1, you make a statement where "it" becomes the subject, taking the place of "that" in the sentence.  Now you have "it", "that", and "a big deal" that you're trying to use to make a comparison.  You can compare any two things.  So what would you see as the role of each?  In #2, there is an implied "of", "of a deal", and "that" is used to emphasize "big" rather than representing something.

Answer (score 2):

"It's not that big a deal" is correct in speech and informal writing. "It's not that a big deal" is not correct.

The structure of the sentence is not common, but it can be used with other adjectives. For instance, I think "He's not that fast a runner" sounds reasonable.

Comment: Could you please provide me with some source material to get into the the intricacies of it?